# Netbeans and Eclipse doesn't show modal window and locks itself on MAC

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, netbeans, ide

I have downloaded Netbeans 8.1 on OSX and when I try to install Darcula theme it is not possible. I press install and the way IDE responds is like situation when user dialogue pops out which locks the application until user acts upon the dialogue. However this dialogue is not visible! The way I know it is there is because when I press ESC button, IDE is responsive back again.

[image: unresponsive IDE with invisible user dialogue]

The same happens when I go to preferences and click "Import" button. Application locks itself but I don't see any dialogue that I can do something about.

This happens also on Eclipse. As you can see in a picture below after I clicked "Add libraries", tab "Libraries" turned from blue to gray because some unvisible window has opened and rest of IDE is unresponsive until I press "ESC"(which usually closes the modal window).

[image]

**EDIT:**
I just found out that this happens when IDE is maximized. So I would like to know if I can fix it somehow that I don't have to un-maximize IDE everytime editor shows me some dialog.

Answer (score 4):

For Eclipse this has been reported as bug [478975](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478975) but as yet there is no fix.